# Getting Error while installing Git for windows 10

Tags: git, installation, windows-10

I am just starting on this GIT thing. So, i downloaded the latest version of GIT (Version 2.27.0) for windows 10. But, whenever i am installing it, it is giving error. Can anybody help me with it.

[image: Error 1]

[![Error 2[image: ][2][2]]
[image: GitConfig Absent]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please copy-paste or screenshot config file in C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig

Comment: While installation, there is no gitconfig file in the directory

Comment: @VaheYavrumian, i have added it in the question

Comment: do you have full admin rights in C:\? Do you have any other version of git installed (including git GUI software that might collide, such as VS, gitKraken, Sourcetree, TortoiseGit...)

Comment: Man I mean the content of config file